# Is it possible to write a Chrome Extension that triggers when an URI with a custom URI scheme is entered?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-extension, uri-scheme

We would like to write a simple Chrome app, that triggers when a user is redirected to an URI in a custom format, something that starts with e.g. `myepicfooapp://some_urlencoded_data_that_the_extension_will_use`.

We have so far been unable to find any reference or documentation about this, although we expect that it is possible because we believe that we're not the first people that want this kind of behaviour in a browser extension.

How can this be made? What parts of Chrome(ium)'s Browser Extension API need to be accessed?

Comment: See [registerProtocolHandler()](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler)